# Integrating $ a\,f(x) +b\,y(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody put me on the right track for integrating the following equation? How do I separate the variables?

$$ a\,f(x) +b\,y(x)=\frac{dy}{dx}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Write down a differential equation solved by $z(x)=\mathrm e^{-bx}y(x)$.

Comment: Thanks that worked. How would I go about finding this solution if I did not know the magic substitution?

Comment: You will have noted that $z=y/y_0$ where $y_0$ solves the homogenous differential equation $y'=by$. To look for (and use) solutions of the associated homogenous differential equation is often a good idea.

Comment: So there is an element of intuition involved - at least regarding how to use the solution to the associated homogeneous differential equation... Many thanks for helping.

Comment: [No intuition needed here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variation_of_parameters#Examples).

Answer (score 0):

That is a linear differential equation of the first order, non homogeneous. It's solution is standard ODE fare...

Comment: Is a first order non-homogeneous DE not $$a\,\frac{dy}{dx}+b\,y(x)+c=0$$. How do I transform the equation in my OP into this form?

Comment: @max, it is $y' + a(x) y = f(x)$, see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_differential_equation#First_order_equation).